# R programming :How to speed up a loop that takes 2 hours and the reasons why it takes a lot

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, data.table

I'm doing a for loop to fill a vector, but this loop is taking 2 hours. I don't know if it is because maybe I'm doing something ineffeciently or if it's just because R is slow with loops. I have to use a loop for this part because I need the previous value so I cannot vectorize the operation.

I'm using the package data.table.
My laptop has 8gb of ram, Intel core i5 pro 2.3GHz.
R version 64 bits 3.2.3

The table has the following structure (It is sorted by NUMDCRED and FDES ascending):

```
NUMDCRED         FDES       Flag_Entrada_Mora  Flag_Salida_Mora   
 0001        "2012-01-01"         0                   0
 0001        "2012-03-01"         1                   0
 0001        "2012-04-01"         0                   0
 0002        "2011-01-01"         0                   0
 0002        "2011-02-01"         0                   0
 0002        "2011-03-01"         0                   0
 0003        "2012-05-01"         0                   0
 0003        "2012-06-01"         0                   1
 0003        "2012-07-01"         0                   0
```

The code uses the Variable FDES, FLAG_Entrada_Mora and FLAG_Salida_Mora to create two new variables Ult_Entrada_Mora and Ult_Salida_Mora. Ult_Entrada_Mora register the last date at which the NUMDCRED entered mora, Ult_Salida_Mora register the last date at which the NUMDCRED went out of mora. When each NUMDCRED is the first (with this I mean the first date at which a NUMDCRED appears) the Ult_Entrada_Mora must be the FDES value and that date must be repeated until is updated each time the Flag_Entrada is 1, with Ult_Salida_Mora each time the NUMDCRED is the first it must register an NA value until is updated by the Flag_Salida_Mora and this one must be repeated until is updated and so on.

In my code First_Numdcred_Index give me the rows where a new NUMDCRED appears, that why I need to check with the %in% if the i value belongs to one of this indexes. aux_entrada and aux_salida are only updated each time one of the events I described before happen.

The table output of the example above would be

```
NUMDCRED         FDES       Flag_Entrada_Mora  Flag_Salida_Mora Ult_En_Mo
 0001        "2012-01-01"         0                   0         "2012-01-01"
 0001        "2012-03-01"         1                   0         "2012-03-01"
 0001        "2012-04-01"         0                   0         "2012-03-01"
 0002        "2011-01-01"         0                   0         "2011-01-01"
 0002        "2011-02-01"         0                   0         "2011-01-01"
 0002        "2011-03-01"         0                   0         "2011-01-01"
 0003        "2012-05-01"         0                   0         "2012-05-01"
 0003        "2012-06-01"         0                   1         "2012-05-01"
 0003        "2012-07-01"         0                   0         "2012-05-01"

Ult_Salida_Mora
     NA
     NA
     NA
     NA 
     NA
     NA
     NA
   "2012-06-01"
   "2012-06-01"
```

Here is the code I'm using to run the loop (`n2 = 648,385`)

`First_NumCred_index` is a vector containing a series of row index of the table. Its length is `148,982` and class `numeric`.
`FDES` is class `IDate` and `Flag_Entrada` and `Flag_Salida` are `numeric`.

```
n2 <- length(Poblacion_Morosa3$NUMDCRED)
Ult_Entrada_Mora <- seq(as.IDate("2020-01-01"),by = "month",length.out = n2)
#vector(mode = "character",length=n2)
Ult_Salida_Mora <- seq(as.IDate("2020-01-01"),by = "month",length.out = n2)

aux_entrada <- as.IDate("2005-01-01")
aux_salida <- as.IDate("2005-01-01")

for(i in 1:n2){ 

 if(i %in% First_NumdCred_index){

    aux_entrada <- Poblacion_Morosa3[i,FDES]
    aux_salida <- NA
   } else if(Poblacion_Morosa3[i,Flag_Entrada_Mora] == 1){

     aux_entrada <- Poblacion_Morosa3[i,FDES]
   } else if(Poblacion_Morosa3[i,Flag_Salida_Mora] == 1){

    aux_salida <- Poblacion_Morosa3[i,FDES]
   }

  Ult_Entrada_Mora[i] <- aux_entrada
  Ult_Salida_Mora[i] <- aux_salida
}
```

I would like to know if it is normal that it takes more tan 2 hours to run or if I'm doing something inefficiently.

Comment: Well, for starters, you can limit the iterations (and remove the if statement) in this way: `for(i in intersect(1:n2,First_NumdCred_index))`

Comment: You should be using `ifelse()` instead of a for loop.

Comment: And, I'm trying to figure out what each piece does. I see you initialize `aux_entrada` to the `FDES` column. But then your first `else if`, if true, also sets `aux_entrada` equal to `FDES` - so it makes no change, right?

Comment: @Gregor: Yep,maybe... but still I'm curious how we can improve this loop... I mean, he's using preallocation of outputs and indexed access to data.table... it seems strange to me that it takes 2 hours...

Comment: @Gregor that's b/c he's using `data.table` which has `with`-like scope inside the `[` expression. @Anflores what is the ultimate goal here? Rather than fix the narrow problem created by your solution it looks as though it would be easier to solve the actual problem for which you designed that solution. You're trying to get two sequences of dates determined somehow by the 1s and 0s sequence in the data; can you express in words the exact way in which the two date sequences are supposed to be determined?

Comment: IIRC data.table works in that way... you don't need to quote the column names, I'm rather doubtful about the row indexing... maybe data.table is searching `i` as it was the key, instead to go to the index directly...

Comment: Ah, didn't catch the data.table tag.

Comment: @digEmAll Indeed; for all `data.table`'s speed this sort of row-by-row access within a for loop is frequently painfully slow compared to a direct `data.table` solution.

Comment: @Philip: Still, 2h for 600K iterations (with very simple calculations) seems too much to me...

Comment: Anyway, on second thought, I guess removing the first if-statement will help **a lot**... it's an `%in%` over 150k elements performed 650k times afterall...@Anflores: have you tried the suggestion on my first comment ?

Comment: ^+1 exactly--the `data.table` lookup is slow, but with the `%in%` it's a killer. Without benchmarks it's hard to pinpoint what is the exact source of what slowness in OP's code.

Comment: Hi, first yes the table is a data.table. I still dont understand why it takes a lot of time to do this very simple loop. The initial values of the aux_entrada and aux_salida doesnt matter as they are going to change. What Im basically doing is if flag salida or entrada is 1 then assign the value of that date to the vector. If the flag salida or entrada is 0 I need to keep the last value the vector had. Thats why the value remains the same if the flags are never 1 . @digEmAll I dont understand your explanation of i is being used as a key.

Comment: @Anflores you should edit that text description into your question, because your code doesn't do anything like what you describe.

Comment: @Anflores try using `library(microbenchmark)` and time some of these commands. In particular you should expect the `%in%` step to take a lot of time because it's making 650k passes of a linear search.

Comment: You may also want to just change the ones that need changing directly and then make a second pass with `zoo::na.locf` or some other function for filling in `NA`s with the previous observed value.

Comment: As an alternative you could also work out something clever along the lines of `dates[cumsum(rle(flag)$values)]`

Comment: @Anflores: my first comment suggestion wasn't correct (sorry, I was deceived by the not perfect indentation of the code), I've just added an answer to remove the `%in%` from the loop if you want to try it...

Comment: @Anflores: about the "i used as key", I'm not sure... I don't want to say wrong thing because I don't use data.table a lot... I'm just having past memories where I used data.table with an integer key then I erroneously tried to access by row index and data.table interpreted that indexes as a key (not as row index)... it's the default behavior I think, but the problem should arise only when you have integer keys

Comment: I already changed my text so It explains better what Im doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, [`findInterval()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/findInterval.html) is the most appropriate function for this problem. Your intermediate variables basically retain their previous values except at known marks within the row sequence, where they change to known values, either fixed (`NA`) or looked up within the input frame (`FDES` column). We can use `findInterval()` to find the closest-previous mark based on the required logic, and index a vector of target values with the winning mark index.

```
## libs
library(data.table);

## generate test data
set.seed(4L);
n2 <- 648385L;
Poblacion_Morosa3 <- data.table(
    NUMDCRED=sprintf('%04d',cumsum(c(T,sample(c(rep(F,3L),T),n2-1L,replace=T)))), ## avg 4 rows per num
    FDES=seq(as.IDate('2011-01-01'),by=1,len=n2),
    Flag_Entrada_Mora=sample(c(rep(0L,5L),1L),n2,replace=T), ## avg 6 rows per flag
    Flag_Salida_Mora=sample(c(rep(0L,5L),1L),n2,replace=T) ## ditto
);

## solution
system.time({
    findLastIndex <- function(iall,imark) c(0L,imark)[findInterval(iall,imark)+1L];
    n2 <- nrow(Poblacion_Morosa3);
    row.seq <- seq_len(n2);
    num.start <- c(T,Poblacion_Morosa3[,NUMDCRED[-.N]!=NUMDCRED[-1L]]);
    entrada.fdes <- findLastIndex(row.seq,which(num.start | Poblacion_Morosa3[,Flag_Entrada_Mora==1]));
    Ult_Entrada_Mora <- Poblacion_Morosa3[entrada.fdes,FDES];
    salida.na <- findLastIndex(row.seq,which(num.start));
    salida.fdes <- findLastIndex(row.seq,which(Poblacion_Morosa3[,Flag_Salida_Mora==1]));
    Ult_Salida_Mora <- c(as.IDate(NA),Poblacion_Morosa3[,FDES])[ifelse(salida.fdes>=salida.na,salida.fdes+1L,1L)];
});
##   user  system elapsed
##  0.328   0.047   0.374
```

---

```
## show result
head(cbind(Poblacion_Morosa3,Ult_Entrada_Mora,Ult_Salida_Mora),50L);
##     NUMDCRED       FDES Flag_Entrada_Mora Flag_Salida_Mora Ult_Entrada_Mora Ult_Salida_Mora
##  1:     0001 2011-01-01                 0                0       2011-01-01            <NA>
##  2:     0001 2011-01-02                 0                0       2011-01-01            <NA>
##  3:     0001 2011-01-03                 1                0       2011-01-03            <NA>
##  4:     0001 2011-01-04                 0                0       2011-01-03            <NA>
##  5:     0001 2011-01-05                 0                0       2011-01-03            <NA>
##  6:     0002 2011-01-06                 0                0       2011-01-06            <NA>
##  7:     0002 2011-01-07                 0                0       2011-01-06            <NA>
##  8:     0002 2011-01-08                 0                0       2011-01-06            <NA>
##  9:     0003 2011-01-09                 1                0       2011-01-09            <NA>
## 10:     0004 2011-01-10                 1                0       2011-01-10            <NA>
## 11:     0004 2011-01-11                 0                0       2011-01-10            <NA>
## 12:     0005 2011-01-12                 0                0       2011-01-12            <NA>
## 13:     0005 2011-01-13                 1                0       2011-01-13            <NA>
## 14:     0005 2011-01-14                 0                0       2011-01-13            <NA>
## 15:     0006 2011-01-15                 0                1       2011-01-15      2011-01-15
## 16:     0006 2011-01-16                 0                0       2011-01-15      2011-01-15
## 17:     0006 2011-01-17                 0                1       2011-01-15      2011-01-17
## 18:     0007 2011-01-18                 1                0       2011-01-18            <NA>
## 19:     0007 2011-01-19                 0                0       2011-01-18            <NA>
## 20:     0008 2011-01-20                 0                0       2011-01-20            <NA>
## 21:     0009 2011-01-21                 0                0       2011-01-21            <NA>
## 22:     0009 2011-01-22                 1                0       2011-01-22            <NA>
## 23:     0010 2011-01-23                 0                1       2011-01-23      2011-01-23
## 24:     0010 2011-01-24                 0                1       2011-01-23      2011-01-24
## 25:     0010 2011-01-25                 1                0       2011-01-25      2011-01-24
## 26:     0010 2011-01-26                 0                0       2011-01-25      2011-01-24
## 27:     0011 2011-01-27                 0                0       2011-01-27            <NA>
## 28:     0011 2011-01-28                 0                0       2011-01-27            <NA>
## 29:     0012 2011-01-29                 0                1       2011-01-29      2011-01-29
## 30:     0012 2011-01-30                 0                0       2011-01-29      2011-01-29
## 31:     0012 2011-01-31                 1                0       2011-01-31      2011-01-29
## 32:     0012 2011-02-01                 0                0       2011-01-31      2011-01-29
## 33:     0012 2011-02-02                 0                0       2011-01-31      2011-01-29
## 34:     0013 2011-02-03                 0                0       2011-02-03            <NA>
## 35:     0013 2011-02-04                 1                0       2011-02-04            <NA>
## 36:     0013 2011-02-05                 1                0       2011-02-05            <NA>
## 37:     0014 2011-02-06                 0                1       2011-02-06      2011-02-06
## 38:     0014 2011-02-07                 0                0       2011-02-06      2011-02-06
## 39:     0014 2011-02-08                 0                0       2011-02-06      2011-02-06
## 40:     0014 2011-02-09                 0                1       2011-02-06      2011-02-09
## 41:     0014 2011-02-10                 1                0       2011-02-10      2011-02-09
## 42:     0015 2011-02-11                 0                0       2011-02-11            <NA>
## 43:     0015 2011-02-12                 0                0       2011-02-11            <NA>
## 44:     0015 2011-02-13                 0                0       2011-02-11            <NA>
## 45:     0015 2011-02-14                 0                1       2011-02-11      2011-02-14
## 46:     0016 2011-02-15                 1                0       2011-02-15            <NA>
## 47:     0016 2011-02-16                 0                0       2011-02-15            <NA>
## 48:     0017 2011-02-17                 0                0       2011-02-17            <NA>
## 49:     0018 2011-02-18                 0                0       2011-02-18            <NA>
## 50:     0018 2011-02-19                 0                0       2011-02-18            <NA>
##     NUMDCRED       FDES Flag_Entrada_Mora Flag_Salida_Mora Ult_Entrada_Mora Ult_Salida_Mora
```

---

Here's a demo on your new test data:

```
## libs
library(data.table);

## generate test data
Poblacion_Morosa3 <- data.table(
    NUMDCRED=c('0001','0001','0001','0002','0002','0002','0003','0003','0003'),
    FDES=c('2012-01-01','2012-03-01','2012-04-01','2011-01-01','2011-02-01','2011-03-01','2012-05-01','2012-06-01','2012-07-01'),
    Flag_Entrada_Mora=c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
    Flag_Salida_Mora=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)
);
Poblacion_Morosa3[,FDES:=as.IDate(FDES)]; ## require correct type for FDES

## solution
system.time({
    findLastIndex <- function(iall,imark) c(0L,imark)[findInterval(iall,imark)+1L];
    n2 <- nrow(Poblacion_Morosa3);
    row.seq <- seq_len(n2);
    num.start <- c(T,Poblacion_Morosa3[,NUMDCRED[-.N]!=NUMDCRED[-1L]]);
    entrada.fdes <- findLastIndex(row.seq,which(num.start | Poblacion_Morosa3[,Flag_Entrada_Mora==1]));
    Ult_Entrada_Mora <- Poblacion_Morosa3[entrada.fdes,FDES];
    salida.na <- findLastIndex(row.seq,which(num.start));
    salida.fdes <- findLastIndex(row.seq,which(Poblacion_Morosa3[,Flag_Salida_Mora==1]));
    Ult_Salida_Mora <- c(as.IDate(NA),Poblacion_Morosa3[,FDES])[ifelse(salida.fdes>=salida.na,salida.fdes+1L,1L)];
});
##   user  system elapsed
##  0.000   0.000   0.003
```

---

```
## show result
cbind(Poblacion_Morosa3,Ult_Entrada_Mora,Ult_Salida_Mora);
##    NUMDCRED       FDES Flag_Entrada_Mora Flag_Salida_Mora Ult_Entrada_Mora Ult_Salida_Mora
## 1:     0001 2012-01-01                 0                0       2012-01-01            <NA>
## 2:     0001 2012-03-01                 1                0       2012-03-01            <NA>
## 3:     0001 2012-04-01                 0                0       2012-03-01            <NA>
## 4:     0002 2011-01-01                 0                0       2011-01-01            <NA>
## 5:     0002 2011-02-01                 0                0       2011-01-01            <NA>
## 6:     0002 2011-03-01                 0                0       2011-01-01            <NA>
## 7:     0003 2012-05-01                 0                0       2012-05-01            <NA>
## 8:     0003 2012-06-01                 0                1       2012-05-01      2012-06-01
## 9:     0003 2012-07-01                 0                0       2012-05-01      2012-06-01
```

Comment: I use the code you post and it worked with my complete table. I just compare the vectors produced with your code with the ones produces with the one I have above (which is really slow) and they produced the same output. I just have one doubt what does Poblacion_Morosa3[,NUMDCRED[-.N]!=NUMDCRED[-1L]] gets? I dont understand the NUMDCRED[-.N]  and the NUMDCRED[-1L] what does each of them? I just know that .N represent the length but what represent the -.N and the -1L.

Comment: Negative integer indexing excludes the specified indexes from the result. See [Extract or Replace Parts of an Object](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html). The statement identifies elements of `NUMDCRED` that do not equal the subsequent element.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a stab at doing what I'm not sure if you're trying to do:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
ex <- data.table(FDES=sample(seq(as.IDate("2001-01-01"),by="month",length=100),
                             1000,replace=T),
                 flag_entrance=sample(c(0,1),1000,replace=T),
                 flag_exit=sample(c(0,1),1000,replace=T))
First_NumCred_index <- sample(1:nrow(ex),250,replace=F)

> ex
            FDES flag_entrance flag_exit
   1: 2003-05-01             0         0
   2: 2007-07-01             1         0
   3: 2004-05-01             0         0
   4: 2008-05-01             1         1
   5: 2008-11-01             1         0
  ---                                   
 996: 2007-11-01             1         0
 997: 2006-05-01             0         1
 998: 2004-04-01             1         0
 999: 2006-11-01             0         0
1000: 2001-11-01             0         1
```

Now we can process this in just a few passes. You could make this a little faster even, but this seems to be fast enough...

```
ex[,`:=`(date.seq.1=as.IDate(NA_integer_,origin="1970-01-01"),
         date.seq.2=as.IDate(NA_integer_,origin="1970-01-01"))]
ex[First_NumCred_index,date.seq.1:=FDES]
ex[flag_entrance==1,date.seq.1:=FDES]
ex[flag_exit==1,date.seq.2:=FDES] 

> ex
            FDES flag_entrance flag_exit date.seq.1 date.seq.2
   1: 2003-05-01             0         0       <NA>       <NA>
   2: 2007-07-01             1         0 2007-07-01       <NA>
   3: 2004-05-01             0         0 2004-05-01       <NA>
   4: 2008-05-01             1         1 2008-05-01 2008-05-01
   5: 2008-11-01             1         0 2008-11-01       <NA>
  ---                                                         
 996: 2007-11-01             1         0 2007-11-01       <NA>
 997: 2006-05-01             0         1       <NA> 2006-05-01
 998: 2004-04-01             1         0 2004-04-01       <NA>
 999: 2006-11-01             0         0       <NA>       <NA>
1000: 2001-11-01             0         1       <NA> 2001-11-01
```

So you have your sequences of dates with NAs preserved where you (apparently?) want them and can recover them as vectors with `ex[,date.seq.1]` etc.

I'm guessing I didn't understand your question. **In particular, you say you need to reference the previous row's values at times.** If this is the case you might combine the suggestion above with a call to `shift`. For example if you need to "take the previous row's value if a condition is met, otherwise use the current row's value," you could do something like

```
ex[,date.seq.3:=ifelse( condition, shift(FDES), FDES)]
```

Best.

**Edit** to expand on my comment. If all you want is "keep repeating the last date until you see a 1, then change to the subsequent date," then you could try something like this:

```
> ex[,.(FDES,flag_entrance,FDES[cumsum(rle(flag_entrance)$values)])]
            FDES flag_entrance         V3
   1: 2003-05-01             0 2003-05-01
   2: 2007-07-01             1 2003-05-01
   3: 2004-05-01             0 2007-07-01
   4: 2008-05-01             1 2007-07-01
   5: 2008-11-01             1 2004-05-01
  ---
```

Be careful of recycling if you copy this vector in the data.table rather than just grabbing the vector.

Comment: I will try it and tell you how it went.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the `%in%` operation inside the loop is taking most of the time. You can remove the it by precalculating the result out of the loop, in this way:

```
isFirstNumdCred <- (1:n2) %in% First_NumdCred_index
for(i in 1:n2){ 
   if(isFirstNumdCred[i]){
      aux_entrada <- Poblacion_Morosa3[i,FDES]
      aux_salida <- NA
   } else if(Poblacion_Morosa3[i,Flag_Entrada_Mora] == 1){
      aux_entrada <- Poblacion_Morosa3[i,FDES]
   } else if(Poblacion_Morosa3[i,Flag_Salida_Mora] == 1){
      aux_salida <- Poblacion_Morosa3[i,FDES]
   }

   Ult_Entrada_Mora[i] <- aux_entrada
   Ult_Salida_Mora[i] <- aux_salida
}
```

Comment: I rewrite my text so it explains better what Im trying to achieve.

Comment: You were correct with this, in my first try removing %in% the time reduced a lot.